# how to make a script to move files from an ftp folder to local

Tags: curl, ftp, wget, move

I'm trying to make a script that move (so download and delete) via ftp all file downloaded by a seedbox (in my case put.io) to a local file (in my case on a Synology NAS)

note that obviously I don't know the name of each file, just the name of the folder where they are

so far I managed to get the download part but I'm stuck with the delete one!

```
#/bin/sh
cd /Volume1/Downloads/
wget -m -np -b -c ftp://username:password@ftp.put.io/putio-sync/
```

Comment: Using an `(s)ftp` client should allow you to delete files. But, if you're not using `linux`, `ftp` clients are notoriously idiosyncratic and unique and without reading **all** of the `man sftp` page you may miss a feature that will verify that a file has transfered correctly and *is now safe to delete on the remote host*. Think about that carefully. Are these production data files that will require having a job rerun if the transfer fails and your script blindly deletes the source file? .... If not prod data, then have at it. (-; Good luck!